# controller_manager query running controllers and switch

Tags: ros, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have a set of **N** controllers "**controller_i**" which all use the same resources.  Intially
when I launch Gazebo and Rviz all the controllers are stopped. What I would like to do is turn off and on the controllers in my code.

I can do this by calling the appropriate controller_manager service, see bellow.

```
ros::ServiceClient                          controller_manager_service;
controller_manager_msgs::SwitchController   switch_msg;

  controller_manager_service = nh.serviceClient<controller_manager_msgs::SwitchController>("/controller_manager/switch_controller");

 switch_msg.request.start_controllers = {{"controller_1"}};
 switch_msg.request.stop_controllers  = {{"controller_2"}};
 switch_msg.request.strictness        = controller_manager_msgs::SwitchController::Request::STRICT;
 controller_manager_service.call(switch_msg);
```

Here decided to start controller_1 and stop controller_2.  **However I would like to know of a way to query the controller_manager to know which controllers are active**.

In this way I can set **switch_msg.request.stop_controllers** to  the currently running controller.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222452/controller_manager-query-running-controllers-and-switch/) by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wouldn't [controller_manager_msgs/srv/ListControllers](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/controller_manager_msgs/html/srv/ListControllers.html) get you the list of controllers (then check `state` field of each [ControllerState](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/controller_manager_msgs/html/msg/ControllerState.html))?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1